# android webview - set referer (for version < 2.2 aka Froyo)

Tags: android, webview

I have a mobile web site and a mobile app for Android that can load this web site in a webview.  I'd like to set the HTTP 'referer' request header from the Android app so that I track what Android app users do.

I there any way to set the HTTP request headers before calling loadURL() in WebView ?

**EDIT:**

It turns out in Froyo (2.2) there is a way to do this as the loadUrl() command has a new parameter to specify extra headers [WebView/loadUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). The comments say you can't override common headers, but I've tested 'referer' and it works fine.

So - still need a **pre Froyo solution** - any ideas ?

Comment: Are you wanting to constantly pass the referer as the users click through links in the webview, or just for the initial loadURL() request only?  If the latter, consider this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035121/http-referer-in-webview-android

Comment: If you want just track users activities, you use UserAgent HTTP header value... if I understood you correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible pre Froyo.  After Froyo you can use the extraHeaders parameter in [loadUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29) to pass HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the user agent using the method setUserAgentString(String ua)

please see WebSettings documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html