# Http Referer in WebView - Android

Tags: android, webview

While developing my simple app that is displaying images in WebView I get some problem.

The images can't be loaded because of redirect me to another page. I found the problem and it is working for me at half. The solution is

For example:

`WebView ww = new WebView(this);`

I try to load an image like this:

`ww.loadUrl("http://i1.kwejk.pl/site_media/obrazki/92825-ism.jpg");`

and image can't be loaded because of redirection.

But when i load an image like this:

`Map extraHeaders = new HashMap();
            extraHeaders.put("Referer", "2");
ww.loadUrl("http://i1.kwejk.pl/site_media/obrazki/92825-ism.jpg", extraHeaders);`

it is working fine.

And the biggest problem is that I'm loading about 10 images in WebView like this:

```
String data="<html><body><img src="link1" /><img src="link2" /><img src="link3" /></body></html>";

ww.loadData(data);
```

And the question is: Is there any possibility to set referer when I'm trying to loadData instead of loadUrl?

Answer (score 2):

here is my very easy solution, just loaddatawithbaseurl

http://androidyou.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-set-android-webview-referrer.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem.

If someone have this anytime too here is solution:

First, you need to download image:

```
Bitmap image;
URL myFileUrl = new URL(urlToImage); 
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "httpReferer");
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Then you need to convert the image Bitmap to String:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
String imgToString = Base64.encodeBytes(bitmapdata);
```

Now, it's easy to display String in WebView like this:

```
String src = "<html><body><img src='data:image/png;base64," + imgToString + "'/></body></html>"
```

Hope it helps.